# What's the alternative to ant: waitfor task if I need to look for a file with a pattern?

Tags: ant

I have to look for a *.xls(say test-results*.xls) in a given folder. If not available, it should wait for 60 minutes for *.xls creation before timing-out. The test-execution target will meanwhile create this test result file.

I am trying to use ant: waitfor task and the associate "available" task for filename. But "available" task expects a specific filename(eg: test-results.xls). I can't have that as the file is appended with time-stamp(eg: test-result_08-22-2012 9:45 PM.xls). I tried using fileset task but it says fileset can't be used within waitfor task.

I have to use ant: waitfor task and look for a file with a particular pattern(say: test-result*.xls or *.xls). Please let me know if that's possible or is there an alternative to waitfor task for this particular scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use this combination [ant-contrib PropertyRegex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) and waitfor task. We have used this combination for our requirement which is similar to yours.